# shared node wise queue

Tags: data-structures, apache-kafka, activemq-classic, shared

I am building a proxy server using Java. This application is deployed in docker container (multiple instances)

Below are requirements I am working on.

1. Clients send http requests to my proxy server
2. Proxy server forward those requests in the order it received to destination node server.
3. When destination is not reachable, proxy server store those requests and forward it when it is available in future.
4. Similarly when a request fails, request will be re-tried after "X" time

I implemented a node wise queue implantation (Hash Map - (Key) node name - (value) reachability status + requests queue in the order it received).

Above solution works well when there is only one instance. But I would like to know how to solve this when there are multiple instances? Is there any shared datastructure  I can use to solve this issue. ActiveMQ, Redis, Kafka something of that kind (I am very new to shared memory / processing).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open Source REST Proxy for Kafka based on Jetty which you might get some implementation ideas from.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

This proxy doesn’t store messages itself because kafka clusters are highly available for writes and there are typically a minimum of 3 kafka nodes available for Message persistence. The kafka client in the proxy can be configured to retry if the cluster is temporarily unavailable for write.

Comment: Thanks for your input, let me give a try